# Trying to apply a class to a parent

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to add a class to a parent of an element on focus on an input field. There is a focus on the input field, but as there is a field add on I want the focus to be round the whole thing hence using the .parent(). I've tried the below and a few other things but can't get it to work.

Here is the HTML:

```
    <div class="input-group">
         <span class="input-group-addon">£</span>
         <input type="text" class="form-control mort-calc-field comma" id="pp">
    </div>
```

Here is the jQuery:

```
   $(document).ready(function(){
     $('.mort-calc-field').onfocus(function(){
     $(this).parent().addClass('calc-box-shadow');
     });
     $('.mort-calc-field').focusout(function(){
     $(this).parent().removeClass('calc-box-shadow');
     });
   });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
   $(document).ready(function(){
     $('.mort-calc-field').focus(function(){
     $(this).parent().addClass('calc-box-shadow');
     });
     $('.mort-calc-field').blur(function(){
     $(this).parent().removeClass('calc-box-shadow');
     });
   });
```

Comment: Thanks, iI've used the other answer but this worked as well.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `onfocus` you need to use `focusin`:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.mort-calc-field').focusin(function() {
    $(this).parent().addClass('calc-box-shadow');
  });
  $('.mort-calc-field').focusout(function() {
    $(this).parent().removeClass('calc-box-shadow');
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="input-group">
  <span class="input-group-addon">£</span>
  <input type="text" class="form-control mort-calc-field comma" id="pp">
</div>
```